# how statistic can up and down like that

Tags: html, seo

I use Google analytics and my statistics are wierd a little bit.
1 day 40-60 sesions, next day 0, after 40-60 ...
Look at that.

[image]

> Language (not set) what is?

Comment: Try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for that is the damn [Referer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam). Take a look at *Acquisition* » *Overview* and you'll probably see something like this:

[image].

If you go through the `Refferrals` you'll see a lot of links such as "free-share-buttons.com".

So you'll need to take the analysis with a pinch of salt. To my understanding, there's not yet a perfect solution to get rid of referer spam although there are different approaches to try to mitigate them.